# System.Reflection GetProperties method not returning values

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Can some one explain to me why the `GetProperties` method would not return public values if the class is setup as follows.

```
public class DocumentA
{
    public string AgencyNumber = string.Empty;
    public bool Description;
    public bool Establishment;
}
```

I am trying to setup a simple unit test method to play around with

The method is as follows and it has all the appropriate using statements and references.

All I'm doing is calling the following but it returns 0

```
PropertyInfo[] pi = target.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

But if I setup the class with private members and public properties it  works fine.

The reason I didn't setup up the the class the old school way was because it has 61 properties and doing that would increase my lines of code to at least triple that. I would be a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: It's kinda obvious, the class doesn't have any properties.  Only fields.  The nightmare got started when you allowed the class to blow up like that.  Using public fields costs more sleep.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You haven't declared any properties - you've declared *fields*. Here's similar code with properties:

```
public class DocumentA
{
    public string AgencyNumber { get; set; }
    public bool Description { get; set; }
    public bool Establishment { get; set; }

    public DocumentA() 
    {
        AgencyNumber = "";
    }
}
```

I would strongly advise you to use properties as above (or possibly with more restricted setters) instead of just changing to use `Type.GetFields`. Public fields violate encapsulation. (Public mutable properties aren't great on the encapsulation front, but at least they give an API, the implementation of which can be changed later.)

Comment: I agree with you completely on using properties instead of fields. I just didn't know the correct syntax. I normally declare private fields and public getters and setters. My problem was that I thought I was using properties when in fact I was missing {get,set}. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This answer really helped me out

Answer (score 4):

Because the way you have declared your class now is using Fields. If you want to access the fields trough reflection you should use Type.GetFields() (see Types.GetFields Method[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3.aspx))

I don't now which version of C# you're using but the property syntax has changed in C# 2 to the following:

```
public class Foo
{
  public string MyField;
  public string MyProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Wouldn't this help in reducing the amount of code?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just had my syntax scrambled. I normally don't declare properties this way. Most of the tiem I have public properties with corresponding private fields.

Comment: But why? Using the short hand syntax compiles to the same IL. The compiler generates the backend field for you. You only need the more elaborate syntax when you want to do some other processing in the getter or setter.

Answer (score 2):

I see this thread is already four years old, but none the less I was unsatisfied with the answers provided. OP should note that OP is referring to Fields not Properties. To dynamically reset all fields (expansion proof) try:

```
/**
 * method to iterate through Vehicle class fields (dynamic..)
 * resets each field to null
 **/
public void reset(){
    try{
        Type myType = this.GetType(); //get the type handle of a specified class
        FieldInfo[] myfield = myType.GetFields(); //get the fields of the specified class
        for (int pointer = 0; pointer < myfield.Length ; pointer++){
            myfield[pointer].SetValue(this, null); //takes field from this instance and fills it with null
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Debug.Log (e.Message); //prints error message to terminal
    }
}
```

Note that GetFields() only has access to public fields for obvious reasons.

Comment: This answer addresses the initial question on fields, even if the author was erroneously using GetProperties() on fields. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, these are fields not properties. The property syntax would be:

```
public class DocumentA  { 
    public string AgencyNumber { get; set; }
    public bool Description { get; set; }
    public bool Establishment { get; set;}
}
```