# Check if all the properties of class are null

Tags: c#, class

I have the following code that should check if all the properties of class are null. I tried the code below but it didn't work. Why?
[image]

Comment: `myUser != null`, but `myUser.CellPhone == null`.

Comment: you are checking class variable for null , not for properties of the class

Comment: Why did you think this works?

Comment: you need to iterate through all properties of your class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/531384/how-to-loop-through-all-the-properties-of-a-class

Comment: i think this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683040/how-to-check-all-properties-of-an-object-whether-null-or-empty

Comment: What if  a null property is perfectly fine in future? This logic seems to be broken.

Comment: You should include the code text instead of an image. Some users turn off images in their browser, or the image may stop being hosted at which point your question would be `null`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make a property `IsInitialized`, that does this internally:

```
public bool IsInitialized
{
    get
    {
        return this.CellPhone == null && this.Email == null && ...;
    }
}
```

Then just check the property `IsInitialized`:

```
if (myUser == null || myUser.IsInitialized)
{ ... }
```

Another option is the use of reflection to walk over and check all properties, but it seems overkill to me. Also, this gives you the freedom to deviate from the original design (when you choose all properties, except one should be null for example).

Comment: With reflection i'd use a method rather than a property to indicate that it's not trivial. But imo the manual approach is much better anyway. However, i'd use a different name which is more meaningful and more flexible like `IsInitialized`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Agree with you Tim. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //NameSpace    
    using System.Reflection;

    //Definition
    bool IsAnyNullOrEmpty(object myObject)
    {
        foreach(PropertyInfo pi in myObject.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if(pi.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                string value = (string)pi.GetValue(myObject);
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Call
    bool flag = IsAnyNullOrEmpty(objCampaign.Account);
```