# Is there a setting on JSON Covert to throw any error if json is malformed

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following json which is malformed, which has missing property value, I want JSON.Convert to throw an error while deserializing, but instead phoneNumber is replaced with `null` when deserialize to strongly typed Object Person, and with dynamic type the value of phoneNumber  is replaced with `{}`, I have tried various JsonSerializerSettings but doesn't seem to help throw an error, is there a way to do this

```
var json=    {
      "firstName": "joe",
      "lastName": "doe",
      "phoneNumber": ,
      "email": "joe.doe@test.com"
    }
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dynamic>(json);
```

Comment: Really?? That sounds like a parser bug.

Comment: @Ryan yeah if tried in other libraries in javascript or python, it just throws an error which is good

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683040/how-to-check-all-properties-of-an-object-whether-null-or-empty (check after deserialization)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit of a work around, but you can mark it with an attribute that a value is required. Which migh or might not work for you depending on your exact case:

```
public class Videogame
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.AllowNull)]
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I preferred using dynamic based on my use case, but let me try with this attribute

Comment: Actually in my use case the property is not a required field, so adding this attribute is will not help

Comment: @inan It might still help if i interpret the documentation correctly: 
Metadata states the following for Required.Always:
"The property must be defined in JSON and cannot be a null value."

Comment: oh wait nevermind... it can be a null value in your case