# Validate two models only if any fileds are filled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I have a view with two models: generic account e profile user.

```
public class AccountModel
{
    [Display(Name = "UserId", Prompt = "UserId", ResourceType = typeof(Strings))]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Validation))]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = null, ErrorMessageResourceName = "InvalidEmail", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Validation))]
    [Display(Name = "Email", Prompt = "Email", ResourceType = typeof(Strings))]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Validation))]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldMaximumLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Validation))]
    [Display(Name = "DisplayName", Prompt = "DisplayName", ResourceType = typeof(Strings))]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "PhoneNumber", Prompt = "PhoneNumber", ResourceType = typeof(Strings))]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Country", Prompt = "Country", ResourceType = typeof(Strings))]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    public SelectList CountryList { get; set; }

}

public class UserProfileModel
{
    [Display(Name = "ID User", Prompt = "ID User")]
    public string IDUser { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Validation))]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldMaximumLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Validation))]
    [Display(Name = "UserFullName", Prompt = "UserFullName")]
    public string UserFullName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Validation))]
    [StringLength(16, ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldMaximumLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Validation))]
    [Display(Name = "Code", Prompt = "Code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Validation))]
    [StringLength(250, ErrorMessageResourceName = "FieldMaximumLength", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Validation))]
    [Display(Name = "Birth Place", Prompt = "BirthPlace")]
    public string BirthPlace { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Newsletter")]
    public bool? Newsletter { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Avatar", Prompt = "Avatar")]
    public string Avatar { get; set; }

}
```

I should validate the second model only if at least one field connected to him has been filled.
If for example `BirthPlace` is entered then also validate the second model, otherwise validate only the first model.
I hope my request is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, probably you want to know how to manually validate the model.

You can use `TryValidateModel(modelInstance);` call to manually validate the required model.

For other conditions you have mentioned in the question, you can add if statements.

e.g. if all string properties of userProfileModelObject are NULL then validate accountModelInstance

```
bool isSecondObjectValid = userProfileModelObject.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    .Select(pi => (string)pi.GetValue(myObject))
    .Any(value => string.IsNullOrEmpty(value));


bool validationResult = false;
validationResult = !isSecondObjectValid ? 
                          TryValidateModel(accountModelInstance) :
                          TryValidateModel(userProfileModelObject);
```

I hope this helps.

**References:**

- [Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683040/how-to-check-all-properties-of-an-object-whether-null-or-empty)
- [MSDN Article on Manual Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2#manual-validation)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how do I pass 2 models to the controller?

Comment: You will have to encapsulate both of them in single model and then pass it in the Post Request as JSON.   Please note that post request does not take two [FromBody] parameters.

Comment: Why Post Request as JSON?

Comment: You have only two ways - either send info in query string or post it.  Better to post it as the details would then be in HTTP body and not in URL.  JSON because your APIs generally use JSON format for interacting with client. Hope this helps.